# change color with css hover without affecting child divs

Tags: css, hover

my original problem involves bootstrap icons inside a div which changes color on hover.
for simplicity, I made the jsfiddle with the follow code to explain the problem

html:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>​
```

css:

```
#parent{
 background-color:red;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;   
}

#parent:hover #child{
 background-color:blue;  
 display:block;    
}
#child{
 background-color:transparent;  
 width:10px;
 height:10px;  
 display:none;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

jsfiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qTdkt/1/)

**The problem**:

the outcome of this code is not what I want to accomplish. I'd like `#child` to appear `background-color: tranparent` but `#parent` to change color to blue.

I know my `:hover` is wrong, but how do I apply 2 different things on one `:hover` (change color of `#parent` and displaying `#child`)?

Comment: i think its not possible ... also chage style of child on hover parent

Comment: You need two selectors. Then it's trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use two selectors, you can't do it with only one, so you can write something like the following:

```
#parent:hover{
 background-color:blue;   
}
#parent:hover #child {
 display:block;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qTdkt/2/

Comment: oh.. I was wondering why the code doesn't do what I am thinking of